# Inconsistency in results when using numpy.median on the dataframe vs list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, median

I wanna find the median of a dataset using *np.median* . But for unexpected reasons, the numpy results differ from each other. If I'm converting the dataframe into a list and than use  `np.median(li)`  I've got 1.0791015625 as a result. However if I'm using `np.median(df['diesel'])`I've got 1.079 as a result. Interestingly using `statistics.median()` works for both versions (using a list or a dataframe). Does anyone know what I did wrong or what could caused this problem?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import statistics
import math

df = pd.read_csv("2020-08-09-prices.csv",sep=',', usecols=['diesel'], dtype={'diesel': np.float16})
df.info()
li=df['diesel'].tolist()

print(df.describe())
print(np.median(li))
print(statistics.median(df['diesel']))
print(np.median(df['diesel']))
```

This is where I got the csv file from: https://dev.azure.com/tankerkoenig/_git/tankerkoenig-data?path=%2Fprices%2F2020%2F08

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just precision of print ?
compare the ourput by np.median(df['diesel']) - statistics.median(df['diesel'])

Comment: given the precision of the data is `1e-3`, I'd say they give the same result.

Comment: @NetanellAvisdris how can I double check that?

Comment: print the dtype of output object, also calculate the diff of both outputs.

Comment: @NetanellAvisdris you're right, I checked it. But do you know how I could print the exact result while using np.median(df['diesel'])?

Comment: if you print with python format use the precision.
i.e. "{:05f}".format(k) for 5 after the pount precision.
what is the precision you care about?

Comment: @NetanellAvisdris hey, 5 after the pount precision is enough. thanks :)